# Slow simulation on LTspice

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice, mosfet-driver

What could be the reason for the slow simulation speed for this converter circuit I have emulated from Fig 9-5: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5145.pdf?ts=1710376974553

[image]

Comment: How slow is slow?

Comment: It depends entirely on the models used and the settings in your simulator.

Comment: Usually TI Pspice models are unstable in LTspice. Try including SPICE directive `.options cshunt=1p` and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @winny takes forever and keeps getting stuck at some time instances... couldn't wait more than 30 mins.

Comment: I expected a numerical value, but nevermind. Have you tried the alternate solver?

Comment: Yes, no change.. it stucks

Comment: What about `.options method=gear` ?

Comment: You could try downloading PSPICE for TI, it's free and TI's models are tested in it.

Comment: You can change the oscillator frequency to a much lower value, change the resistor on the RT pin. In real life you want a high frequency to minimise the output ripple. In a simulation that doesn't matter much.
A lower frequency results in less pwm periods to calculate.

Answer (score 4):

You have your "Maximum Timestep" parameter set to 10ns in your .tran statement.

This is why it is taking very long. The simulation is computing 10ns worth of data a time. Running total simulation of 5ms at this timestep will take very long. Removing the maximum will allow the simulation to run at variable timestep.

Open the .tran settings and delete any maximum timestep.
Should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Then it shows time step too small error..

Comment: It shouldn't give that error when no maximum time step is set. What does your new .tran statement say?

Comment: Now I am putting .tran 0 5m. It says : Analysis: Time step too small; time = 0.000191076, timestep = 1.25e-19

Comment: I see, the simulation must not be converging then. One guess, should SYNCIN be tied to ground? You have an RT resistor so maybe it should be floating.

Comment: According to the schematic, SYNCIN is connected to VCC through 20k resistor.